# The menu defined from my module returns a 404 error

Tags: drupal, drupal-routes

I am new to Drupal. I have created a contace1 module with the following code:

#### contace1.info

```
; $Id$
name = Contact1
description = Show how to build contact form
package = Pro Drupal Development
core = 6.x
```

#### contact1.module

```
// $Id$

/**
* @file
* practice to build form
*/

/**
* Implimentation of hook_menue().
*/

function contact_menu()
    {
        $items['contact1'] = array(
            'title' => 'Contact',
            'page callback' => 'contact_page',
            'access argument' => array('access content'),       
            'type'=>MENU_CALL_BACK,
            'access callback' => TRUE,
            
            );
            return $items;
    
    }
    
/**
* menu callback
* called when user goes to http://localhost/drupaldemo/?q=contact
*/

function contact_page()
    {
        $output = t('You can leave a message using the contact form below.');
        //Return the html generated from $form data structure.
        $output.= drupal_get_form('contact_nameform');
        return $output;
    }
    /**
    * define the form
    */
function contact_nameform()
    {
        $form['user_name']= array(
        '#title' =>t('Your Name'),
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#description' => t('Please enter your name.'),
                );
        $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        )       ;
        return $form;
    }
    
/**
* validate the form
**/
function contact_nameform_validate()
    {
        if($form_state['values']['user_name']=="")
            {
            form_set_error('user_name',t('Please enter your name.'));
            }
    
    }
    
/**
* handle post validation form submition
*/
function contact_nameform_submit($form ,&$form_state)
    {
    $name=$form_state['values']['user_name'];
    drupal_set_message(t('Thanks for filling out the form, %name',array('%name'=>$name)));
    
    }
```

im this code i have tried to create new contact form

but it does not show any link and on opening page directly give page not found.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, `MENU_CALL_BACK` does not defined in Drupal. What you wanted to write is `MENU_CALLBACK`, which registers a menu item in the menu router. This item won't appear in any visible menu normally. Think of it as a hidden menu item. If you want to make it visible, use `MENU_NORMAL_ITEM`.

Comment: flush the menu cache (on your admin panel, there is subpage called `Performance`; on the bottom of that page there is a `Clear all caches` button)

Answer (score 1):

'type' = MENU_CALL_BACK - menu is callback, you should set it to MENU_NORMAL_ITEM or manually create menu in admin page to contact1 page. Refresh cache.

I recommend to you fully read "Pro Drupal Development" from Vandyk, there's examples how to create forms :)

Answer (score 0):

The first error in the code is that, if the module is named contact1.module, then every hook it implements should have a name starting with contact1_. You should then avoid using contact_ in the name of your module's functions, as there is already the Contact module in Drupal 6; in the case your module is for Drupal 6, there would be a conflict between the modules.

The second error is that the constant you are using is `MENU_CALLBACK`, not `MENU_CALL_BACK`.

If then contact1.module is the name of your module, the info file that comes with it should be named contact1.info, not contace1.info. If you use a wrong name for that file, Drupal 6 and higher should not show your module in the list of the modules you can install.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to use this code

```
/**
* menu callback
*
*/

function contact_page()
    {
        $output = array(
            'item 1' => array(
              "#type" => 'markup',
              '#markup' =>  t('You can leave a message using the contact form below.'),
            ),
            'item 2' => array(
              "#type" => 'markup',
              '#markup' =>  drupal_get_form('contact_nameform'),
            ),
        );
        return $output;
    }
    /**
    * define the form
    */
function contact_nameform($form, $form_state)
    {  ..........
       .......
```

Here,I set **markup** type to return output with content and form, also set the parameter of  **contact_nameform($form, $form_state)**